# GROUP BY clause ignoring first column value if second and third are the same

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

Database server is MySQL

I have an SQL query that does a select with a "GROUP BY" clause as follows:

```
SELECT col1, col2, col3, SUM(col4), SUM(col5) where col6 = 20 GROUP BY col1, col2, col3
```

All works well when col2 and col3 have different values but when col2 and col3 have the same value as follows

```
col1    col2   col3   col4   col5
a       1      2       1      1
b       1      2       2      2       
b       1      2       3      3
c       1      2       4      4
```

the query result is

```
c       1      2       10     10
```

I was expecting

```
a       1      2       1     1
b       1      2       5     5
c       1      2       4     4
```

Why does the "GROUP BY" ignore the fact that the col1 values are not all the same and just displays that last one it finds?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Your expectation is correct.  I suspect that the query you are actually using is different from the one in the question.  The most likely cause is that `col1` is missing from the `GROUP BY`, but other things might be happening as well.

Comment: What is filtering in 'Where col6 = 20' ?

Comment: You have added col6=20 in where clause but your table structure doesn't show that column

Comment: *casts suspicious glance towards col6 too*

Answer (score 0):

User error - turn out I was aliasing col1 and there was a column of the same name in the table so the GROUP BY was using the column name and not the alias. The column name is question was not even part of the query.

The pitfalls of working on a system that someone else wrote.

Thanks for all your suggestions/comments